# Coordinates of a matrix w.r.t. some basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let us consider a basis of some vector space to be

$$\mathcal{B}=\left\{\mathbf{b}_1, \mathbf{b}_2..., \mathbf{b}_n\right\}$$

If we have a linear operator $A$, its matrix elements $a_{ij}$ with respect to this basis are given by

$$A\mathbf{b}_j = \sum_{i} a_{ij}\mathbf{b}_i$$

How is this relationship obtained? I am only aware of the case where the basis is orthonormal and then one can use the expression

$$a_{ij} = \mathbf{b}_i^* A \mathbf{b}_j$$

I see that the above relationship is more general and would like to know how it is derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's introduce some notation. For a vector $v=\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i$, we define

$[v]_{\mathcal{B}} = (a_1, a_2,... ,a_n)$

That is, $v$ expressed in the basis $\mathcal{B}$. Call the matrix representation of the a linear operator $L$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ $[L]_{\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B}}$. Then a fundemental theorem of matrix representations of linear operators tells us that for a vector $v$ written as before, we have

$[Lv]_{\mathcal{B}} = [L]_{\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B}}[v]_\mathcal{B}$

In particular, we have first that since $[b_j]_{\mathcal{B}}=(0,...0,1,0,...,0)$, where the 1 is on the jth place, we get

$[Ab_j]_{\mathcal{B}}= [A]_{\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B}}[b_j]_\mathcal{B}
= (a_{1j}, a_{2j},...,a_{nj})$

From this and by defintion of $[Ab_j]_{\mathcal{B}}$, we get that

$Ab_i = a_{1j}b_1+...a_{nj}b_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}b_i$

Edit: Explanation of last lines of equations. $[Ab_j]_\mathcal{B}$ is simply the vector you get by applying the linear operator to the vector $b_j$, and then expressing it in the basis $\mathcal{B}$. How we get the equality $[A]_{\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B}}[b_j]_\mathcal{B}
= (a_{1j}, a_{2j},...,a_{nj})$ is just matrix multiplication when we express the i,jth entry of $[A]_{\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B}}$ as $a_{ij}$.

The last equalities is how you go from calculating with linear operators to calculating with matrices. I would imagine it is a definition of the matrix representation in your book.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't follow the last line. What is the definition of $[Ab_j]_{\mathcal{B}}$ that allowed you to write the last equalities? Thank you